# "Object Not Found" Error When I Use In Source Editor In R

Tags: arrays, r, object

I tried to turn X into an array in the Source Code Editor using RStudio:

```
  > x <- 1:9
  > ax <- array(X)
```

R returned this error message:

```
Error in array(X) : object 'X' not found
```

However, it worked properly when i typed the same scripts in the Console.

Why is that?

Comment: R is case sensitive    x != X

Comment: wow! overlooked that. thank you!